# how to solve this linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the differential equation is :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=f(x),~~~~~~~~ y(0)=0$$

where,

$$f(x)=\cases{2,& if $0\le x\lt1$\\0,& if $x\ge 1$}.$$

So what i did was....

since it is a linear differential equation, i calculated its I.F(integrating factor)= $e^x$

and used..

$$y(I.F)=\int (e^x f(x)+c\tag{1})\,dx.$$

Now, how should i use the splitting of $f(x)$ to solve for $y$ in $(1)$

Please help

Comment: Another approach is Laplace transforms.

Comment: @Amzoti i have no idea of that, i'll look into it for sure.

Comment: write up two solution in the different range and match them at the boundary by requiring $y$ to be continuous. the derivative  will certainly  have a jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solving for $y$ in the interval $[0,1],$ you find $y = 2 -2 e^{-x}$ and $y(1) = 2 -  2/e.$
use this as the initial value and solve $\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y = 0$ to get $y = 2(e-1)e^{-x}$ for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: oh yeah, got it. thnks